# Dynamic array in an array of structures in OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a struct :

```
struct A
{
double a;
int c;
double *array;
}
main()
{
A *str = new A[50];
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
str[i].array = new double[5];
str[i].array[0] = 50;
}
.....
Buffer BufA = Buffer(...,..., 50 * sizeof(A),str);
.....
}
```

In kernel

```
struct A
{
double a;
int c;
double *array;
}

__kernel void vector(__global A *str)
{
int id = get_global_id(0);
printf("Element - %f",str[id].array[0]);
}
```

But in the kernel does not see the value in the array. Probably, because in the buffer I allocated memory for an array of structures without the memory of a dynamic array. How can I implement this?

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language. Since there's a `new` in your snippet, I've removed the C tag. Don't use it next time for a C++ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of the address virtualization mentioned by **YSC**, you should also keep in mind that the memory that your graphics card (or other OCL device) is operating on may be distinct (as in, different pieces of hardware) from the memory your CPU is operating on.

The OpenCL buffers are responsible for transporting their contents between these memories. So for example an array of `int`s that you create and write to on the CPU would have to be copied to GPU memory (and have space allocated there, and possibly be copied back after the kernel is done), which these buffers do for you. But if you store pointers to *other* CPU memory in your buffer, then that other memory will *not* be transferred automatically. Further, the pointer relation would most likely break, as there is no guarantee that your other data is at the same location in GPU memory as in CPU memory.

The solution, naturally, is to put all the data you want transferred into buffers, including the sub-arrays. One way to do this without using excessive amounts of buffers would be to pack the sub-arrays together into one and storing indices into it instead of pointers to memory.

Comment: Now I at least understood what the difference is with the transfer of the variable and the pointer. Thank you so much. Also, I was thinking about making a huge array, which will be shared by each core

Comment: And if I specify in the structure an array with a fixed length. Is it possible to transfer an array in the structure? It just does not work either

Comment: Having a `double array[5];` member should work just fine I think. The buffers almost surely `memcpy` your data, and as the data for the fixed-size array is directly within the struct, I don't see a problem. But you should probably ask a new question if you can't make it work.

Comment: Can you see the question please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970079/how-to-pass-an-array-in-a-structure-to-the-kernel

Answer (score 3):

On modern system, a process doesn't see the actual addresses of objects, but rather the [*virtual* addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of such objects.

This means, two processes cannot pass each others pointers and expect them to mean the same thing. You need to rethink your application with that in mind.

Comment: Can you explain this question to me in more detail, I do not understand you, if it's not difficult for you?

Comment: Nope, i just started to understand these things and it's hard to understand many of the designs. Can you give a link?

Comment: @Fresto Let's play a game. I've hidden a link _in my answer itself_. Try and find it. (yes, it was there all along)

Comment: I don't like the way it's rendered, it's easy to miss.