# How to pass an array in a structure to the kernel?

Tags: c++, opencl

I need to output to Kernel an array of structures in which there will be an array. But in the end, the data is a little correct, but in some way the error.
I have this code on Host

```
struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    double b;
    double c[5];
};

myStruct *result = new myStruct[countOptim];

for (int i = 0; i < countOptim; i++)
{
    result[i].a = 5;
    result[i].b = 11.5;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        result[i].c[j] = j;
    }
}

// Make kernel
Kernel kernel(program, "vector_add");

Buffer bufferResult = Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, countOptim * sizeof(myStruct));

queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(bufferResult, CL_TRUE, 0, countOptim * sizeof(myStruct), result);


kernel.setArg(0, bufferResult);


// Run the kernel on specific ND range
NDRange global(countOptim);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, NULL, global);
```

And this code on Kernel

```
struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    double b;
    double c[];
};
typedef struct myStruct myStruct;

__kernel void vector_add(__global myStruct *result) 
{


   // Get the index of the current element to be processed
   int id = get_global_id(0);

   printf("a - %d, b - %f, c[0] - %f",result[id].a, result[id].b, result[id].c[0]);
}
```

In the console displays this
[image]

Perhaps the problem is in memory

Okey, this is fixed by specifying the size of the array in the Kernel. But is it possible to do without set size of the array in kernel?

Comment: The size of your two structs is different, so it will read probably read garbage (and this matches the pattern of outputs). `double c[];` is not the same as `double c[5];`, the first is the size of a pointer and the latter the size of five doubles - I don't know if you can do the latter in OpenCL though.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I already think that we will just set the maximum possible size, but I will use the size that I specify in the input parameters. This is the only way out that I see

Comment: If you want to use a fixed-size `c`, its size must be set at compile time (i.e. in the declaration), because a `double c[]` results in a different (incompatible) struct than `double c[5]`.
Alternatively, you could store/transfer all your `c` data in a single buffer somewhere and just store indices (and lengths) into that buffer in `myStruct`.